# Difference between ${2\over 9}$ and ${22\over 99}$?

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

The fractions  ${2\over 9}$ and ${22\over 99}$ both have the same decimal value $0.22222\ldots$ But obviously they are not equal. What causes this situation?

And also, what is the correct rational form of $0.2$ recurring?  ${2\over 9}$ or ${22\over 99}$ or anything else?

Comment: Why is it obvious that they are not equal? ;)

Comment: Are you arguing that they could be equal? Hmm...*deep thoughts*

Comment: calculate their difference!

Comment: **Tip:** $\frac {22}{99} = \frac 2 9\times \frac {11}{11}$

Comment: But $\frac{2}{9} = \frac{22}{99}$. So what?

Comment: They are different ways to represent the same number, much like $2 = \frac{4}{2}$

Comment: Have you learned how to show that $\frac68=\frac34$? This is basically the same thing.

Comment: These are just two different *fractions* that represent the same *rational number*.

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac29 = \frac29\cdot\big(1\big) = \frac29\cdot\left(\frac{11}{11}\right) =\frac{2\cdot 11}{9\cdot 11} =\frac{22}{99}$$

Placing rational numbers into decimal form you will find that they either terminate ($1/4$ for example), or repeat for ever, like the $2/9$ you found. I recommend trying some long division on integers divided by $11$, or $7$. You ultimately will see why the patterns repeat based on the remainder from the previous digit.

Answer (score 2):

To answer in a more formal way than you are probably looking for,  rational numbers are defined as an equivalence class.  The form of the class looks like $[(a,b)]$  where $a,b$ are both integers and $b\ne 0$.   In this sense, $[(a,b)]=\frac a b$.  We call it an equivalence class because there's a whole set of members that are equivalent to each other.  For instance $\frac 1 2=\frac 2 4$,  so in this parlance we'd say $(1,2)\in [(2,4)]$, or visa versa....they are all part of the same set.    Each fraction has an infinite number of representations,  that's what we call the particular pair of integers used to form them.  The rule of when two fractions are equal is the rule of cross multiplication:  $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ if $ad=bc$

So in short:  Rational numbers have an infinite number of representations, all for the same number. No particular representation is more "proper" than another,  although it's common to use "reduced" form, where you require  the gcd of $a$ and $b$ to be 1,  and $b>0$,

Comment: Yeah, this is probably much more formal than what he was looking for.

Comment: Agreed,  but strangely enough my "in short" I added at the end was the only one that answered his question as to what was the correct form of a given fraction.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of repeating decimals
$$\frac{1}{9} = .1111111111\cdots$$.
Any multiple of this value leads to a repeating similar pattern. As examples defined by this problem:
\begin{align}
.2222\cdots &= \frac{2}{9} \\
&= \frac{22}{99} \\
&= \frac{222}{999}\\
&= \cdots
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If the fractions **have the same value** (whether expressed in decimal or not), then **they are equal**, because 'equal' means 'having the same value'.

So there is no question.